# Problems with animateAlong in IE7

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm having trouble making a simple shape move along a path in IE7 (the only version of IE I tried, actually). The following code works fine in chrome and firefox, but not IE. I couldn't find an obvious reason, has anybody seen something similar?

```
canvas.path(rPath.path).attr("stroke", "blue");
var circle = canvas.circle(rPath.startX, rPath.startY, 5);
circle.animateAlong(rPath.path, 3000, true);
```

My rPath variable has the path and the starting point coordinates.

Microsoft script debugger points to this line as the one where the code breaks:

```
os.left != (t = x - left + "px") && (os.left = t); (line 2131 inside the uncompressed raphael.js script file, inside Element[proto].setBox = function (params, cx, cy) {...})
```

Any ideas? Any experience (good or bad) with raphael's animateAlong in IE7?

TIA,
Andrei

Comment: FWIW, I've used animateAlong in IE7 before; what version are you using?

Comment: I was using 1.4.2, but just upgraded to 1.4.3 and I'm seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the original coordinates of the moving circle, rPath.startX in my example. It was obtained by splitting a string, therefore a string value. While the positioning of the circle worked fine, the animateAlong was not as forgiving in IE.

Parsing it to an int before using it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create a circle using a real path..

Take this code...
paper.path('M325 35a200 200 0 1 0 1 0' );

and play with it here...
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.html?q=animateAlong

Comment: Thanks. Running the code from this site in my page works, so it's definitely something with my code (albeit it works fine in Chrome and FF). I narrowed it down to the coordinates I create the circle at, but haven't figured out what exactly could be the problem, yet.